# Git: Unable to pull from Bitbucket repo on new system

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-bash, ssh-keys, git-clone

I recently got a new Mac, and it comes with Git installed. I tried to pull from a repo, it asked me for my password, I entered the password for the Bitbucket account with which I have access to the repo, and it said `Login failed due to incorrect login credentials or method`

Is there something I need to set up locally in order to be able to pull from a Bitbucket repo? For example, do I need to "log in" to Git locally? This is also a new Bitbucket account, and I haven't set up an SSH key or anything. I think I did that a long time ago with my previous account.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are trying to authenticate via SSH: the problem must be that there are no SSH keys registered that belong to your new Mac. So the repo at Bitbucket will not recognize you. Create a pair of new SSH keys on your Mac (private key and public key) and then register the -public- key at the Bitbucket website (Personal Settings > SSH Keys).

If you need more details, Bitbucket has a [how-to for macOS](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-personal-ssh-keys-on-macos/) to help you in creating a new pair of SSH keys to work with.

---

If you are cloning a repo via HTTPS (`git clone https://username@bitbucket.org/...`) and the repo is private, then you are going to need something that can handle the auth process for you.

Since you´ll be using your user account to authenticate it is likely you´ll have to deal with two-factor authentication or other interactive/multi-step process to get access. Maybe the issue here is that you are missing that part in your new Mac?

You can use [GitCredentialManager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) to handle the auth process for you. In macOS you can [install GitCredentialManager using brew](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager/blob/release/docs/install.md).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for your insight on SSH. The repo I'm trying to pull from uses https though. Do you know how I should handle that instead?

Comment: I edited my original answer.